# Should I have a dedicated thread for watching a timeout?

Tags: java, multithreading

Right now I have two threads running in my program. One constantly tries to read input from the user, and the other watches for a timeout. A timeout occurs if the user does not send any input in a given amount of time. The two threads look like this:

User input thread

```
while(true){
    if(in.hasNextLine()){
        processLine(in.nextLine());
        timeLastRecieved = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Timeout thread

```
while(true){
    //Check for a timout
    if(timeLastRecieved+timeoutDuration <= System.currentTimeMillis())
        timeUserOut();

    else{
        //Sleep until it is possible for a timeout to occur
        Thread.sleep((timeLastSent+timeoutDuration) - System.currentTimeMillis());   
    }
}
```

As of now I have these thread separated, but I could combine them like this...

```
while(true){
    if(in.hasNextLine()){
        processLine(in.nextLine());
        timeLastRecieved = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    //Check for a timout
    if(timeLastRecieved+timeoutDuration <= System.currentTimeMillis())
        timeUserOut();
}
```

But I really don't need to check for a timeout that frequently. So should I combine the threads and check for a timeout too often, or should I have two threads. I am not as worried about performance as I am proper coding etiquette. If it means anything the timeout duration in something like 15 minutes long.

EDIT: Just want to point out that in the version with two thread I am sleeping, but in the combined version I never sleep the thread. This obviously causes the if statement that checks for a timeout to run more then necessary.

Comment: If the reading thread polls for user input anyways it could handle the timeout as well. After all, if I understand you correctly, it's a timeout for waiting for input and thus the consumer thread (which polls) would be the one that times out anyways. The only reason I'd see for having a separate thread check for timeouts would be if the processing of the user input would take too long and if, for example, the next poll would occur after 16 minutes and the user provided input after 15:30 the polling thread doing both might not recognize the timeout.

Comment: Additionally you might want to consider putting `timeLastRecieved = System.currentTimeMillis();` before processing the input since otherwise the time needed for processing would increase the threshold for the timeout - which you might or might not want to happen.

Comment: good point @Thomas. I am not to worried about the length of the processing because it shouldn't be more than a few milliseconds, while the timeout is set to around 15 minutes. The root of my question is whether it is better to have two efficient threads, or one thread that executes an if statement more often then necessary.

Comment: I'd not bother with a single if-statement, especially not such a simple one as checking one primitive value against some other. To optimize your code a bit you could calculate the anticipated timeout whenever you get input instead of calculating it every iteration. Additionally, if performance might matter, you could have your polling thread sleep for some ms, the user would probably not even notice it anyways.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is inter thread communication: to use 2 threads you'd have to share `timeLastRecieved` between and might even have to synchronize access or at least use an atomic wrapper (AFAIK writing longs might not be an atomic operation and thus could cause subtle bugs).

Comment: As an alternative to one timeout thread per user you could use `java.util.Timer` to schedule a timeout check for the time you anticipate it. The check would then execute, check whether a timeout occured and if not just stop itself (and if you receive input before the timeout you could cancel and reschedule the timeout task - or have the timeout task spawn a new one for the current anticipated timeout).

Comment: Thank you. Again I am more concerned with etiquette than performance because I am about to hand this code to someone above me and I want it to be as "clean" as possible.

Comment: In that case I'd opt for the simpler version, i.e. have the polling thread check for the timeout. That makes reading and understanding the code easier and probably more robust as well. Besides that "clean" is somewhat subjective  (apart from some obvious code smells that should be avoided) and might depend on what your organization does in general.

Comment: Thank you again. If you want to submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize my comments: I don't think a separate thread to check for timeouts is necessary.

Reasons:

- You'd need to share information like `timeLastRecieved` between them, which could be more complex than wanted (e.g. AFAIK in some cases access to `long` values is not atomic).
- From your description it seems that polling for user input and timeout (no input provided in time) are closely related, thus the polling thread could check for the timeout as well. That doesn't mean it has to handle the timeout too, just reporting it somewhere or calling some timeout handler might be better design.
- It is easier to read and understand since updating `timeLastRecieved` and checking for a timeout is handled in the same place.
- Since there is no inter-thread communication nor coordination needed (there are no threads that need to communicate) it probably is more robust as well.

A few hints on checking for the timeout:

- You should calculate the timeout threshold when you update `timeLastReceived` and then only check agains the current time instead of calculating it in every iteration.
- You might want to calculate the timeout threshold before processing the input in order not to have it depend on the processing time as well.

Finally, there are alternative approaches like using `java.util.Timer`. Here you could simply schedule a timeout task which is executed when the timeout should occur. That task then would check if the timeout really happened and if not it just returns.

To handle new input before the timeout occured you could use at least two approaches:

- Cancel the current timeout task, remove it from the timer and schedule a new one.
- If there is already a scheduled timeout task then don't schedule a new one but wait for the current one to run. The current one then checks for the timeout and if none happened it schedules a new task (or itself) for the current anticipated timeout (note that this would require some inter-thread communcation so be careful here).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two threads - one waiting for data coming in through the InputStream / Reader, and one that's watching the time to see if the time elapsed as taken too long. The only way to do it with 1 thread would be to sleep for a segment of the timeout period and then poll for data periodically. But that's less efficient than having a separate thread dedicated to reading from your InputStream/Reader.

You may want to check out [Timeout](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/TimeOut.java) as a generic option for implementing a timeout